# matrix and multiplication numbers

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

i cant complete my code ,the number of column stop on 1 number missing and this error comes:

```
enter the number of rows2
enter number of columns4
0 0 : 2
0 1 : 2
0 2 : 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\py.py", line 9, in <module>
    first[i][j]=int(input())
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

this is my code pls till me where is my mistake , iam a bignner in programming

```
a=int(input("enter the number of rows"))
b=int(input("enter number of columns"))
first = [[0]*a for i in range(b)]

for i in range (a):
    for j in range (b):
        print (i,j,":",end=" ")
        first[i][j]=int(input())
        
#total=0       
#for t in range(b):
    #for s in (b):
 #       total+=first[i][j]
#print(total)
```

the purpose of code is the user should enter number of rows and number of columns after that he should enter the number of inside matrix and finally the program result the total of all numbers

Comment: Try switching "a" and "b" (numbers rows and columns) in the "first=" initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line

```
first = [[0]*a for i in range(b)]
```

is unnecessary and you can use append instead.

```
first = []

for i in range (a):
    first.append([])
    for j in range (b):
        print (i,j,":",end=" ")
        first[i].append(int(input()))
```